# how to re upload our app to appstore

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store, itunes

Last week i have launched my app to app store after two days i got a metadata rejection from the review due to providing invalid demo account later i provided my valid account after again they came up with other issues that is

Hello,

Thank you for your response and for providing this information.

However, upon further review we noticed that your app does not comply with the following guideline:

Guideline 5.1.5 - Legal - Privacy - Location Services

Your app uses background location services but does not clarify the purpose of its use in the location modal alert as required in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

Please see attached screenshots for details.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription value in the Info.plist to specify the intended purpose of using the user's location while the app is in the background.

Resources

For additional information and instructions on configuring and presenting an alert, please review the Requesting Permission section of the iOS Human Interface Guidelines and the Information Property List Key Reference.

We look forward to reviewing your revised app.

Best regards,

App Store Review

But still my app store status is showing metadata rejected.Now what should i do whether i need to update my proper reasons in plist and rebuild to launch my app or else any other steps to follow????

Comment: In your app when you are using user location? I mean u need user location in background too?

Comment: did you re-submit the app after adding key in your plist?

Comment: No i did n't re-submit my app @ gagan

Comment: @user3549189 so how you would be able to get the update on App store. Please modify your app's plist file, create new build & upload it again. Everything would work fine

Comment: @user3549189 please see this link for upload process  https://www.raywenderlich.com/127939/submit-an-app-part-2  I would suggest u can take help from a developer if you are not aware of the process & need to upload urgently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the proper reason of why you need the location service in the App.

You can set it by following way

Steps

1. Go to info.plist file.
2. Add your reason of accessing location service under key "`Privacy -
   Location Always Usage Description`"
3. You will see the plist like this after adding the location service

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have also faced the same issue even after adding  NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription with description in info.plist My App has rejected by apple.If we use `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` you need to explain how you are going to use user location. But in my situation While initializing LocationManager i have changed `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` to `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` Hope it will work for you too.

Comment: what is difference between both locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() to locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

Comment: locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()  will use user location while using app, where as  locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() will always use even user not using app.

Comment: yes i need to fetch the location when app moves to background

Comment: Then use locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() with a valid reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your application is rejected because of the insufficient justification of using the location services in the background.You should add description for alert why your application is using the location in background in NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in info.plist file of your project. As well as you should mention it in your application description as well that why your application is using location services in background.(i.e for geo-fence or track user location.) Also mention that "continuous use of location may drain the battery dramatically" in application description.

By these steps you will be able to successfully submit your application to the apple store.

Comment: can you explain how to resubmit my app

Comment: Since it is metadata rejection you just need to change description and click submit for review to upload the binary. You will not require to upload new build for this.

Comment: but they asking to change plist?? will they accept by only changing to the description

Comment: In case of metadata rejection we do not require to resubmit the build. But if it is binary rejection then you should go for resubmitting the build by increasing the build version and uploading it to the store.

Comment: now what should i do whether go for a new build or adding valid reasons in description

Comment: can you share the screenshot of your resolution centre of apple account so that I can assist you properly?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` with description in `info.plist`
2. Go to your Project settings and increment the build number.
3. Upload a new build and submit your app again.

Comment: we should increase our version number??

Comment: Oh build no not version no. Sorry

Comment: If you have not yet submitted single version before you no need to change version number. Just change build number.

Comment: so i dont need to change version number in anywhere am right??

Comment: where is that option to change build number?? i think i just need to add latest build thats it??

Comment: in xcode settings my build shows 1 now i need to change that to 2??

Comment: @Surjeet added screenshots in an other answer

Comment: In metadata rejection we do not need to resubmit the build.It is require only in the case of binary rejection.

Comment: Yes change it to 2 and upload your app again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your **info.plist** file and add **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** key with description.
2. **Change (Increase) your build number** (highlighted in attached image)

[image]

3. Re-upload your app to Itunes Store and submit for review.

Comment: now i also need update the description that why am fetching location??

Comment: Yes, you need to write description to display user, why app is asking for  location permission.

Answer (score 0):

You Must upload new Binary because your change is in your app's Info.plist file. See Next Step in your rejection message.

After add valid reason in info.plist file. Make app build with higher version.

Go to AppStore and Click on + button With increment app version. Add new Binary after deleting old One. and Upload for Review.